# When running docker on Windows 11 interactive shell (in admin mode), apt-get update gives "permission denied". What to do?

Tags: docker

I want to install some application in my docker container, but when I go into an interactive bash shell and try to apt-get I get permission denied.

I am running the docker container in Windows 11 admin mode.
What can this mean?
[image]